# Android add unlimited new views dynamicly on same position after dragging

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

I am developing an app that the user can choose an image and drag it to another position (adding images in to a canvas drawing).
I now need that the original ImageView location will still have another image to choose.

So the user can actually choose many of the same image for his drawing.
How can I make that the original /imageView position will always "refill" itself after drag ?

I have tried addView() but then the new view and the first view have the same ID and when user tries to move the new view, it also moves the first one.